# Setting Chinese characters in a request header with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a jQuery post request in which I'm setting some information provided by a client in the header. The call looks something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : myURL,
    type : "POST",
    beforeSend : function(request){
        request.setRequestHeader('someInfo', clientInformation);
    },
    data : someData,
    contentType : "text/plain",
    success : successCallback,
    error : errorCallback
});
```

This works fine (most of the time), but if the client enters Chinese characters into the data that I'm passing in the variable `clientInformation`, the request fails with the message: `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest':`, followed by the request and then `is not a valid HTTP header field value.`

I tried setting the encoding by including this line in the `beforeSend` portion of the request, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
  "application/x-www-form-url-encoded; charset=utf-8");
```

How do I configure my ajax request to send Chinese (or other non iso-8859-1) characters?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The cause for the error is that the custom header contains non ASCII characters.

To handle such strings you have to URL encode them:

```
request.setRequestHeader('someInfo', encodeURIComponent(clientInformation));
```

Or if you are altering the Referrer as in my case:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Referrer", encodeURI('http://example.com/马轶群'));
```